# Algorithms for covering a rectilinear polygon using the same multiple rectangles

Tags: polygon

All angles of the polygon are right.  It may be convex or concave.

Use the same rectangle to cover the polygon. The edge of the polygon and rectangle are parallel with the coordinate axis.  Overlapping between rectangle is allowed.

The objective is to minimize the number of rectangles and to minimize the overlap.

I have no background with computational geometry. I searched online and find many algorithms use different rectangles to cover the polygon.

Does anyone know some algorithms to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me, if I'm wrong, but it seems, like you are searching for an [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral).

Comment: Quoting the article I linked to "...mathematical definition of the integral.. is based on a limiting procedure which approximates the area of a curvilinear region by breaking the region into thin vertical slabs." In your case it's polygonal, but it works anyway. See this picture, for example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Integral_approximations.svg/220px-Integral_approximations.svg.png